# Delphi 7 vs C# expression evaluation

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7

I have a Delphi-7 expression as below, all variables are of type longint-

```
cy:=((s1 and s2)or((s1 or s2)and not res))shr 31;
```

And in C# the expression is, all variables are of type int-

```
cy = ((s1 & s2) | ((s1 | s2) & (~res)))>>31;
```

where

```
s1  = -659459908
s2  =  283372503 
res =  217426595
```

When *Delphi 7* evaluates it, and I look the value of expression to the right by quick watch it shows value as -1, but when I `ShowMessage(IntToStr(cy))`, it shows **1**.

Whereas C# still shows **-1**.

I am working on Windows-10 64 bit system and compiling the code for Any CPU from VS2013. I tried declaring the C# variables as Int32 as well, but same phenomenon occurs.

Can anyone tell about this phenomenon, what we say this and how to proceed further.

Comment: Mistakenly written. question is updated. All variable in delphi are of type longint. where as in C# all are type of int.

Comment: In Delphi `shr` is logical shift. In C# `>>` is arithmetic shift. Which do you want? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: Well, clearly C# and Delphi is different. Pick one and implement the other differently.

Comment: Yes it is coming as negative by all C#, Delphi-7 and calculator. but ShowMessage is showing it as '1'.

Comment: The C# documentation states _If the first operand is an int or long, the right-shift is an arithmetic shift (high-order empty bits are set to the sign bit)._ The Delphi documentation states that it does NOT preserve the sign bit: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)

Comment: Does `cy` in Delphi contain -1 or 1 before that ShowMessage?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Delphi evaluates expression ((s1 and s2)or((s1 or s2)and not res))shr 31 as -1 but assigns 1 to cy.

Comment: What you mean is that the debugger is evaluating in a different way compared to the compiled code. That sounds about right as an observation for Delphi 7, there's plenty of such mismatches. (those are bugs in in the Delphi debugger, make no mistake)

Comment: @Prateek Yes, that's a debugger defect. Don't trust it. You still haven't told us whether you want arithmetic or logic shift. Do you know?

Comment: We are performing bitwise operation(arithmetic shift).

Comment: So you are happy with the C# code and want to implement arithmetic shift in Delphi?

Comment: Why bitshift at all?  It's an unneccesarily obfuscated way to check if the number is negative or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# `>>` operation *preserves* the leftmost bit when opertaing with *signed* integers like `int`, `long` (alas C# doesn't have any `>>>` operation as in *Java*), when Delphi's `shr` *doesn't*:

In both cases (C# and Delphi) we have the same evaluation for the inner formula

```
// -79459485 (decimal) == 11010000101000110111000111011100 (binary) 
((s1 & s2) | ((s1 | s2) & (~res))) == -794594852
```

The final step (`-794594852 >> 31` and `-794594852 shr 31`) is *different*:

```
11010000101000110111000111011100 >> 31 == 11111111111111111111111111111111 (C#)
11010000101000110111000111011100 >> 31 == 00000000000000000000000000000001 (Delphi)
```

Amendment (let C# mimic Delphi):

```
 unchecked { 
   cy = (int)((uint)((s1 & s2) | ((s1 | s2) & (~res))) >> 31);
 }
```